# Laravel where date - what does it actually do? Should I Carbon::parse it?

Tags: laravel, date

I set up a laravel api to take a couple date strings as query parameters,

So for example I would do this in my javascript:

```
axios.get(`/apiuser/${this.state.user.id}/request-breakdown.json?start=${encodeURIComponent(start.toISOString())}&end=${encodeURIComponent(end.toISOString())}`)
```

Sending through start and end query parameters as ISOString dates

Now, on the laravel side of things, my initial idea was to `Carbon::parse` these dates

```
Model::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->get('start')))
     ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($request->get('end')))
```

But I played around a little bit and I discovered I apparently didn't need the `Carbon::parse` at all:

```
Model::where('created_at', '>=', $request->get('start'))
     ->where('created_at', '<', $request->get('end'))
```

As far as I can tell, both of those results are correct.

I just wanted to know, **what's the correctly Laravel way**? And **are there advantages to one way over another**? For example, maybe I should be using `Carbon::parse` because it will allow me to accept more formats of dates to be passed through?

Comment: Most database engines will take a stab at converting a date *string* into an actual date. If you're sending a standard format like `2019-08-02 13:30:52` from your front-end to the back-end, either approach is fine, and the `Carbon::parse` isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to answer from personal experience as I don't have the SQL know-how to explain *why* it happens in depth. I've stopped using `where('date', '>=', date)` because the results can be a bit erratic. I suppose this is due to how dates are stored, sometimes we have `date` formats and `datetime` formats and sometimes the input dates are different.

It seems like using `whereDate('date', '>=', Carbon::parse(date))` provides the most reliable returns. There are post stating that `whereDate()` wraps the column in the table with `DATE()` function, so it is a little more taxing on resources. Since you are already passing the dates in ISOString that is probably why you are not seeing any real world impact, but if you were trying to query for `08-02-2019` I would suggest using Carbon.